# Button in the footer of tableview section Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uibutton

I have a footer in the section of my tableView.
I try to add a button, in the center, and after to center my button.
I didn't find how I can center my button, I try to use view.center, or give him the width of all the parent view and after use a text align for center my button. (Personally I prefer use the second method .)
Actually my code is this one

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView()
    let labelMore = UIButton()
    footerView.addSubview(labelMore)
    labelMore.sizeToFit()
    labelMore.setTitle(footerText(status: "Test"), for: .normal)
    labelMore.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
    footerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
    //labelMore.addTarget(self, action:#selector(footerMore(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return footerView
}
```

And I got, the green square is actually my button, I erase from my code labelMore.frame = footerView.frame, because that don't work [image: The green square is my button]

edit: If my question is not clear I want center my button.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Is what are you trying to do to let the button to be in the center of `footerView`?

Comment: I want my button, take all the blue space(footerView) and after to center it, thanks for your note, i will edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the code you showed "centers" the button, so it is not surprising that it is not centered. You do not set the `frame.origin` of `labelMore` at all, so its origin is zero — the top left corner, exactly as shown in the screen shot.

> I erase from my code `labelMore.frame = footerView.frame`

Yes, well that was never going to work. It's just another case of confusing `frame` and `bounds`. Remember, the `frame` of the subview is in terms of the `bounds` of the superview. So you would change that code to

```
labelMore.frame = footerView.bounds
```

However, that isn't going to work either because `footerView` has no bounds — you haven't given it any size!

The *real* solution here is to position `labelMore` using autolayout. That way, no matter how `footerView` ends up being sized, `labelMore` will have the correct position within it. For example, let's assume that you want `labelMore` to be the same size as `footerView`:

```
    let footerView = UIView()
    let labelMore = UIButton()
    footerView.addSubview(labelMore)
    labelMore.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    labelMore.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    labelMore.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    labelMore.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    labelMore.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // ... and remove the `sizeToFit` ...
```

Comment: Actually when I try your code, and give at your view some color let's say red for the footerView and blue for the button.
I actually see only the red background with no blue  background button .

Comment: Sorry, I left out a line of code. Added it (see edited answer).

Comment: He works perfect, thanks for the explanation about frame and bounds